# How to push user to an object, PHP to JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

Let me start of with how I want the desired code to look;

```
{
"user1": {
    "password": "from var",
    "token": "from var",
    "demo": true,
    "userlevel": [
        "user1*"
    ]
},
"user2": {
        "password": "from var",
        "token": "from var",
        "userlevel": [
            "user2*"
        ]
},
"user3": {
        "password": "from var",
        "token": "from var1",
        "demo": true,
        "userlevel": [
        "user3*"
        ]
    }}
```

This is the PHP code I have right now, it does the formatting right, I just don't know how to put for example user4 in the same object as the other 3 users.

I was thinking of array push ( edit, I did try it, didn't get it to work. ), but I'm not too sure;

```
$message = '';
$error = '';
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
     if(empty($_POST["name"]))
     {
          $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter username</label>";
     }
     else
     {
          if(file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../../users2.json'))
          {
               $current_data = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../users2.json');
               $array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);
               $extra = array(
               $_POST['name'] => array(
                    'password'               =>     $passwordencrypted,
                    'token'          =>     $token,
                    'demo'     =>    true,
                    'userlevel'     =>    [$_POST['name'] ."*"]
                  )
               );
               $array_data = $extra;
               $final_data = json_encode($array_data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
               if(file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../users2.json', $final_data))
               {
                    $name = $_POST['name'];
                    $message1 = "<strong><br>Account for ".$_POST['name']." made!</strong></p>";
                    $message2 = "<strong>Username:</strong> ".$_POST['name']."<br>";
                    $message3 = "<strong>Password:</strong> $password"."<br>";
                    $message4 = "<strong>Password encrypted:</strong> $passwordencrypted"."<br>";
                    $message5 = "<strong>Token:</strong> $token"."<br>";
                    $message6 = "<strong>Demo:</strong> true"."<br>";
                    $message7 = "<strong>Example link:</strong> https://example.com/login.php?name=$name&token=$token"."<br>";
                    $message8 = "<strong>Demosite link:</strong> https://example.com/?name=$name&token=$token"."<br>";
               }
          }
          else
          {
               $error = 'JSON File does not exist';
          }
     }
}
?>
```

This outputs for example, only user1, in the correct way, how do I push for example user4 in the same object as user1,2,3.

Comment: _"I was thinking of array push, but I'm not too sure"_ - Just try it out.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I did try it out, didn't get it to work

Comment: `$passwordencrypted` and `$passwordencrypted`? Passwords shouldn't be encrypted. They should be hashed using `password_hash()`

Comment: Then you need to tell us that. Show us what you've tried and what happened when you did.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson They come from a function that uses password_hash()

Comment: Ah, I thought it said password**de**crypted at one place. My bad.

Comment: Since this has been answered I also want to give a different tip, make sure that you sanitize $_POST[‘name’] for any unwanted data, rule of thumb anything coming from the browser should be filtered out :)

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg Thank you, will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually replacing the value before you are putting on the file:

You should do something like:

```
$current_data = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../users2.json');
$array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);

$extra = array(
    'password' => $passwordencrypted,
    'token' => $token,
    'demo' => true,
    'designs' => [$_POST['name'] ."*"]
);

$array_data[ $_POST['name'] ] = $extra;

$final_data = json_encode($array_data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_data[] = $_POST['data']; //new posted data
$temp = json_decode(file_get_contents('users.json')); //get existing data from file in temporary array
array_push($temp, $new_data); //push new element into temporary array
file_put_contents('users.json', json_encode($temp)); //encode and put all values into file
```

These are the steps you need to follow to append new node to the existing JSON.